# Save Spark StandardScaler for later use in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am still using Spark 1.6 and trained a StandardScalar that I would like to save and reuse on future datasets.

Using [the supplied examples](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html) I could transform the data successfully but I can't find a way to save the trained normaliser.

Is there any way in which the trained normaliser can be saved?

Comment: That's because it's not a model. It's just standardized data, so you actually just have to save the data as it is.

Comment: Thanks eliasah. Not sure I agree though, the normaliser should contain an array of means and standard deviations that enable the standardisation transformation. So basically I'm looking for a way to these this and apply to a new dataset. The ml (and not mlib) package has a save function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have created the `scalerModel`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScalerModel

scalerModel.write.save("path/folder/")

val scalerModel = StandardScalerModel.load("path/folder/")
```

Answer (score 0):

*StandardScalerModel* class has a *save* method. After calling the *fit* method on *StandardScaler*, the returned object is *StandardScalerModel*: [API Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScalerModel)

e.g. similar to the supplied example:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel

val dataFrame = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

val scaler = new StandardScaler()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
  .setWithStd(true)
  .setWithMean(false)

// Compute summary statistics by fitting the StandardScaler.
val scalerModel = scaler.fit(dataFrame)
scalerModel.write.overwrite().save("/path/to/the/file")

val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/path/to/the/file")
```